# What might be the error here with my face detection code?

Tags: object-detection, p5.js

I am expecting the imagesnapshot (Image) to be returned and print on the canvas with the face detected enclosed within the box but now the Image is not being printed out but there is no errors within the console.

I am wondering if there is any errors within my code. I am using objectdetection.js in P5.js.

Thanks.

```
function DetectFaces() {
 var Image = createImage(imageSnapshot.width, imageSnapshot.height);
 
   //imageLoadedCallBack();
 
 faces = detector.detect(Image.canvas);
 
   //print(faces);
 
 strokeWeight(2);
 stroke(0);
 noFill();
 
 for (var i=0; i<faces.length; i++){
 var face=faces[i];
 print(face);
 if (face[4] > 4){
 print(faces[0],faces[1],faces[2],faces[3]);
 rect(face[0], face[1], face[2], face[3]);
     }
   }
 return Image;
 }
```

```
My draw function

function draw() {
  background(255, 192, 192);
  var gapValue = 5;
    
    if (imageSnapshot) {
      

    // Fifth row with three images
    image(DetectFaces(imageSnapshot), 0, 4 * columnWidth, columnWidth - gapValue, columnWidth * imageSnapshot.height / image.width);
        
      //remember to put the edge detection back into the code.
        
  } else {
    image(video, 0, 0, 160, 120);
}

}
```

I am expecting the imagesnapshot (Image) to be returned and print on the canvas with the face detected enclosed within the box.